# Purge any rows not accessed within n days

Tags: sql-server, caching, sql-server-2014

I'm trying to implement an LRU cache in SQL Server where rows in a table are purged if they're not accessed within a certain period of time. My initial (possibly naive) approach is to add a `LastAccessed` column which gets updated on each query, and then have a periodic job query for records older than n days. Are there better ways to do this?

Comment: Your method is quite reasonable.

Comment: Make sure that `select` statement doesn't fire any event. It means that data should be accessible through SP only. Update a column (read full row) may slow down performance.